# c# error passing a string in POST from jquery to a WebAPI project method

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I'm doing something seemingly easy.
I have a jquery function that call a WebApi project method (c# visual studio 2013). This method accept a string in input as parameter.

this is my javascript code

```
function insert() {                       
    var tag='test';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        url: 'api/TAGS/InsertTAG',
        data: tag,
        success: function (msg) {
            $("#result").html(msg);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("fail");
        }
    });
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApiGet",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{filter}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, filter = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult InsertTAG([FromBody] string tag)
{
    var da = new TagsDataAccess();            
    return result = da.InsertTAG(tag);
}
```

The ajax call is successful but the parameter tag that arrives in InsertTAG is null.

where am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Content-Type` should really be just `contentType`. The code you've posted should not be working in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POST payload should be:

```
data: '=' + tag,
```