# FromBody string input not binding in REST web service

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, post

I am trying test out a REST service implemented as follows:

```
public bool loadData(string file, string page, string mapping, [FromBody]string value)
{
    // Implementation
}
```

The code I am using to invoke this service:

```
uri = "http://localhost:9576/API/DataLoaderService?file=F&page=P&mapping=M";
HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
req.Method = Method.ToUpper();
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("TEST_STRING");
req.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
Stream PostData = req.GetRequestStream();
PostData.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
PostData.Close();
HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

However the "TEST_STRING" does not get bound to the [FromBody]string value.

Comment: Look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618471/web-api-put-is-recognizing-query-strings-but-not-body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566614/c-sharp-error-passing-a-string-in-post-from-jquery-to-a-webapi-project-method) my previous question (little different from yours) when you use `[FromBody]` you should use `=` and then the value of the parameter.

So in your case try

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("=TEST_STRING");
```

instead of

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("TEST_STRING");
```